# jquery replace with "script"

Tags: jquery, html, google-tag-manager

Currently, I'm trying to replace a div class with a script through the jquery or replace appendto function, but it's not working

The following sample works with `reg.html`

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("<br><center>").appendTo(".ad2");  
    });
</script>
```

sample with `script`

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js />')
      .appendTo(".ad2");
    });
</script>
```

doesn't run.

Comment: We're gonna need more information than that. Do you see an error? Did you check if `$('.ad2')` actually existed?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a \ before /script and it should resolve your issue.